Where does this expression for Green's function come from?
In the context of $2$nd order ODEs, I found in some solution sheet that they computed the Green's function using the following expression
$$G(x;x')=\dfrac{y_2(x)y_1(x')-y_1(x)y_2(x')}{\overline{\mathrm W}(x')},$$
where $\overline{\mathrm W}$ is th Wronskian, and $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to
$$a_0(x)y''+a_1(x)y'+a_2(x)y=0.$$
How did they derive it? Moreover, what's the difference with that other piecewise definition,
$$G(x;x')=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\dfrac{y_1(x)y_2(x')}{a_0(x')\overline{\mathrm W}(x')},\enspace a\leq x<x'\\
&\dfrac{y_1(x')y_2(x)}{a_0(x')\overline{\mathrm W}(x')},\enspace x'< x\leq b
\end{aligned}\right. \qquad?$$

Both $G$s are Green's functions, but of different kinds. The first one, also known as fundamental solution, does not adress boundary or initial conditions. It yields a particular solution to the inhomogeneous differential equation
$$
y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=f(x) \tag{1}
$$
through the formula
\begin{align}
y_p(x)&=\int_{x_0}^xG(x;x')f(x')\,dx' \\
&=-y_1(x)\int_{x_0}^x\frac{y_2(x')f(x')}{W(x')}\,dx'+y_2(x)\int_{x_0}^x\frac{y_1(x')f(x')}{W(x')}\,dx', \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are any pair of linearly independent solutions to the corresponding homogeneous differential equation, and $x_0$ is an arbitrary parameter.
Equation $(2)$ can be derived using the method of variation of parameters.
The second Green's function is used when one wants to find a solution to $(1)$ subject to boundary conditions of the form
\begin{align}
\alpha_1 y'(a)+\beta_1 y(a)&=0, \tag{3.1} \\ 
\alpha_2 y'(b)+\beta_2 y(b)&=0. \tag{3.2}
\end{align}
The solution, in this case, is given by
\begin{align}
y(x)&=\int_a^b G(x;x')f(x')\,dx' \\
&=y_2(x)\int_a^x\frac{y_1(x')f(x')}{W(x')}\,dx'
+y_1(x)\int_x^b\frac{y_2(x')f(x')}{W(x')}\,dx', \tag{4}
\end{align}
where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to the homogeneous differential equation associated with $(1)$ that satisfy the boundary conditions $(3.1)$ and $(3.2)$, respectively.
